# urllib2.open giving 500 HTTPError exception even when call is successful

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am using urllib2 to access a URL and read the data. The urlopen call is in a try except block like below. I have seen other questions asked on the site saying they are encountering this 500 error but I could not find a concrete answer as to why we get this 500 exception even when the call is successful. Can anyone elaborate on that or point out ways to encounter it?

```
            try:
                data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().split('\n')
            except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                print "Could not get data with url {0} due to error code {1}.".format(url,e.code)
            except urllib2.URLError, e:
                print "Could not get data with url {0} due to reason {1}.".format(url,e.reason)
                sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 500 is a server error (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). You should investigate the server side logs

Comment: I know that 500 error is server side but what I asked in my question was the error comes up even when the url call is successful. Say I am accessing an api with my above try except block, the data comes in find into the **data** object and even then the 500 error comes. I am looking into answers to get better troubleshooting data than the 500 error code.

Comment: I saw your original comment (about still getting data) -- the point I was trying to make was the server is telling you something about the request failed. It may have been right at the end -- but the server definitely encountered an internal error. I doubt there is any further intelligence you can glean from the client side without checking server logs unless you can somehow determine server state by carefully examining the data restore -- which I suppose is possible. If you want to go this route. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a server side error.

You need to inspect the error (`e`) to see if there is any feedback on what is causing it.  it usually has some of the actual error data from the server in it. not all servers will return error data though, sometimes it's just on the server logs.

If this is running on a daemon, or sporadically, you could write something that logs the contents of `e` somewhere.

You could also use `pdb.set_trace()` to set a breakpoint and inspect the object yourself.

also, while this line looks great:

```
 data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().split('\n')
```

it's a real pain during debugging and troubleshooting, which happens A LOT when using urllib.

i would suggest splitting it into a few lines like this

```
url_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = url_obj.read()
data = data.split('\n')
```

if you enter in a few breakpoints with `pdb` ( `pdb.set_trace()` ) you'll be able to instead each variable.

since you're not using a custom opener, i would also just use the `requests` library, which just wraps urllib and makes it less horrible.